# is this RPC methods related about : deploy or call contract?

Tags: rpc, contract

[image]

but the doc have't example. really bad.

Comment: Please update/clarify this question as it looks too much like a duplicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No - these are helper functions that provide typecheck and testing features.

You originate a contract via an operation (with kind origination), and you call it via a standard transaction and the parameter field.